# how to drop multiple functions in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to drop multiple functions from my database at a time in Oracle's SQL developer.
Is anyone has an idea how to create a script for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the *static* option to drop the functions (sometimes considered **more secure** as you can double-check what you are removing) consist of two steps

1 - run the following query

```
select 'drop function '||object_name||';'  as sql_txt
from user_objects where object_type = 'FUNCTION' 
and object_name like 'F%' /* filter the selection here */
order by 1;

SQL_TXT                                                                                                                                        
-----------------
drop function FA;
drop function FB;
drop function FC;
```

2 - copy the result `drop` statements in SQL Developer window and execute them

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have to know which ones you want to drop. I named them all in the `IN` clause in the script that follows.

Test functions first:

```
SQL> create or replace function f1 return number is begin return 1; end;
  2  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace function f2 return number is begin return 2; end;
  2  /

Function created.
```

Do they work?

```
SQL> select f1, f2 from dual;

        F1         F2
---------- ----------
         1          2
```

Yes, they do.

Let's drop them in a script:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select object_name
  3                  from user_objects
  4                  where object_name in ('F1', 'F2')
  5                    and object_type = 'FUNCTION'
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      execute immediate 'drop function ' || cur_r.object_name;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Do they work now?

```
SQL> select f1, f2 from dual;
select f1, f2 from dual
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "F2": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

No, as they are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can choose.

**1. Generating SQL query to drop the functions**

**2. Using PL/SQL**

#########################################################################

**1. Generating SQL query to drop the functions**

```
SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION ' || OBJECT_NAME || ';' FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION') AND OWNER = 'schemaName';
```

Above query generate below queries,

ex :

1. DROP FUNCTION function_1;
2. DROP FUNCTION function_2;
3. DROP FUNCTION function_3;

After generating the all queries, you can execute them one by one or all in one as a script in SQL Developer.

#########################################################################

**2. Using PL/SQL**

```
DECLARE
    schemaName VARCHAR2(10) := 'your_schemaName';
    l_query VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN

    -- drop all functions
    FOR objName IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION') AND OWNER = schemaName)
    LOOP
        l_query := 'DROP FUNCTION ' || objName.OBJECT_NAME;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query;               
    END LOOP;
    
    -------------------------- example to drop all tables, types, procedures ------------------------------------
    -- drop all tables
    FOR objName IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE') AND OWNER = schemaName)
    LOOP
        l_query := 'DROP TABLE ' || objName.OBJECT_NAME;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query;               
    END LOOP;
    
    -- drop all types
    FOR objName IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TYPE') AND OWNER = schemaName ORDER BY OBJECT_ID DESC)
    LOOP
        l_query := 'DROP TYPE ' || objName.OBJECT_NAME;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query;               
    END LOOP;
          
    -- drop all procedures
    FOR objName IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE') AND OWNER = schemaName)
    LOOP
        l_query := 'DROP PROCEDURE ' || objName.OBJECT_NAME;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query;               
    END LOOP;
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    COMMIT;
END;
```